# calcular saldo inicial debe haber saldo y saldo acumulado en oracle sql apartir de tabla destino

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

necesito hacer el siguiente calculo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SALDO inicial= primer sueldo
DEBE o haber se tiene de DEBE_HABER con la siguiente condicion debe si es 'S' y haber si es 'H' lo valores se toman en base a los importes:IMPORTE01, IMPORTE02, IMPORTE03, IMPORTE04, IMPORTE05, IMPORTE06, IMPORTE07, IMPORTE08, IMPORTE09, IMPORTE10, IMPORTE11, IMPORTE12)
SALDO=  debe-haber
SALDO_ACUM frecuencia acumulada de saldo

debo tomar todos estos campos para mi nueva tabla  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo el siguiente código pero no me esta dando bien el calculo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]